# jsf expression language (el) classes function life scope

Tags: java, jsf, scope, el

What is the scope of static classes used in el language?

I assume application scope?

I tested it in debug mode and that lazy loaded attribute is only initialized once in multiple windows, browsers.

```
private static Object[] objects = null;

public static Object[] getObjects()
{
    if(ElClass.objects == null)
        //init objects
    return ElClass.objects;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means of a concrete instance. The EL functions class is not even constructed. EL functions are intented to be entirely stateless. Static variables are per definition JVM-wide (or application wide as you call it). In normal Java code you would also just do `ELClass.getObjects()` instead of `new ELClass().getObjects()`.

As to your particular example, I recommend to do the initialization just in a static initializer block. That lazy loading is unnecessary.

```
private static final Object[] objects;

static {
    // Init objects.
}

public static Object[] getObjects() {
    return objects;
}
```

I also recommend to add a private constructor so that you prevent that the functions class can ever be constructed.

```
private ELClass() {
    // Prevent construction.
}
```

Comment: Learned something new, did not knew about that static block! That no construct Constructor looks still like a bad Java Design. But what if the utility class gets large and with a lot of method of this type. Loading all of them eagerly in that static block could be overhead?

Comment: The private constructor is definitely not bad design if the class is stateless and has only static methods. IDEs and codestyle checkers will even warn you whenever you call static methods on an instance. If the class gets large, just split over multiple classes. Look for example in Apache Commons libraries. The overhead is negligible if it happens only once during class loading.